# When does time shuffling a stochastic process make it independent in time?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I am interested in discrete time stochastic processes $X[t]$ such that when we shuffle its time points completely at random, the resulting process $X'[t]$ becomes independent in time. By independent in time, I mean $X'[t]$ becomes independent of $X'[t-1]$ for all $t$.

Do all Ergodic and Strict-Sense Stationary random processes have this property?

Comment: A standard definition of i.i.d. requires all random variables to be mutually independent, not just that each variable is independent of its predecessor.

Comment: It would help to know what the time horizon is, is it finite $t \in \{0, 1, 2, ..., T\}$?  Otherwise, what is meant by shuffling an infinite number of time indices "completely at random"?

Comment: @Michael  You are right. It was a typo in the main question. It is now edited.

Comment: @Michael assume that the horizon is a finite $t$ as you mentioned.

Comment: In that case, what about a 2-slot horizon, $t \in \{0, 1\}$. Now consider a stationary and ergodic DTMC with two states $0$ and $1$ with transition probabilities $P_{01} = \epsilon$, $P_{10}=1/2$, where $\epsilon>0$ is very small. We start off in steady state, and then we shuffle the times swapping time 1 and 0 with probability $1/2$.  Now it is quite likely both variables are $0$, but if we know one of them is $1$, then the chance that the other is 1 is considerably larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a stationary and ergodic (and reversible) DTMC $\{X[t]\}_{t=0}^{\infty}$ with two states $\{0,1\}$ and with transition probabilities $P_{01}=\epsilon$, $P_{10}=1/2$, for $0<\epsilon<1/2$.  The steady state is:
$$P[X=0] = \frac{1/2}{1/2+\epsilon}, P[X=1] = \frac{\epsilon}{1/2+\epsilon}$$
Assume the initial distribution at time $0$ is this steady state distribution.
Now consider just the first two time steps $X[0], X[1]$.  We reshuffle them randomly:
$$ (X'[0], X'[1]) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
(X[0], X[1]) & \mbox{ with prob 1/2} \\
(X[1], X[0]) & \mbox{ with prob 1/2} \end{array}\right.$$
By reversibility, we have that $(X'[0], X'[1])$ has the same distribution as $(X[0],X[1])$. So
\begin{align}
P[X'[0]=1, X'[1]=1] &= P[X[0]=1, X[1]=1] \\
&= P[X[0]=1]P[X[1]=1|X[0]=1]\\
&= \frac{\epsilon(1/2)}{1/2+\epsilon} 
\end{align}
However
$$P[X'[0]=1]P[X'[1]=1] = \frac{\epsilon^2}{(1/2+\epsilon)^2} \neq \frac{\epsilon(1/2)}{1/2+\epsilon} $$
So $X'[1]$ and $X'[0]$ are not independent.

---

More generally, fixing a time horizon $T$, I think the real question to ask is if  the desired independence property holds for **any** processes that are not already i.i.d. processes.

Comment: This is a perfect counterexample to the argument! I also believe that the this property does not hold for non indep. stochastic processes if we fix a finite time horizon. However, I think that there might exists examples that we can make X' as indep as we want (!, in some sense!) by making the time horizon long enough. I believe a random phased sinusoidal might be a good example.

Comment: Yes, for a finite state ergodic DTMC I believe we can make the time horizon long enough so that the fraction of time getting each state is "close" to the steady state distribution, so that a random reshuffling looks approximately pairwise independent.